# Using Perl with Sed and Capture Groups to add another string to end of a string

Tags: perl, sed

I have a requirement to go through each file and add a new string at the end of a particular statement in the file. I already have the list of each such file (actually each file is a SAS code) having this statement . My aim is to edit each file in-place after creating a backup first.So i have decided to use PERL to do this in-place editing on a AIX 7.1 machine.
The particular statement that i intend to add to in each file will always have  3 keywords :FILENAME, FTP  and HOST identifying such a statement and it is always terminated by a semicolon. The statement can also occur multiple times in same file.

Example of the statement in the file is:

```
    FILENAME  IN   FTP  "" LS  HOST=XXXX USER=XXXX PASS=XXXX ;
```

The same type of statement also be in multiple lines as well with some additional options on the statement.

```
    FILENAME  Test   FTP  "Sample.xls" 
    CD="ABCDEFG"
    USER=XXXXX
    PASS=XXXXX
    HOST=XXXXX
    BINARY
    ;
```

OR

```
    filename Novell ftp &pitalist.
        HOST=&HOST.          
        USER="XXXXXXXX"
        PASS="XXXXXXX"
        DEBUG
        LRECL=10000;
```

My  aim is add a new string : **%ftps_opts** at the end of the above string  just before ending semicolon.There should be atleast one space or a newline between existing statement and this new string as shown below.

```
    FILENAME  IN   FTP  "" LS  HOST=XXXX USER=XXXX PASS=XXXX %ftps_opts;

    FILENAME  Test   FTP  "Sample.xls" 
    CD="ABCDEFG"
    USER=XXXXX
    PASS=XXXXX
    HOST=XXXXX
    BINARY
    %ftps_opts;

    filename Novell ftp &pitalist.
        HOST=&HOST.          
        USER="XXXXXXXX"
        PASS="XXXXXXX"
        DEBUG
        LRECL=10000 %ftps_opts;
```

Is there a way to use  Capture group and PERL  to capture the existing statement in each file  **just before** the semicolon and then  append the new string at the end of it with a space or newline? The Input.txt files has list of files having the FILENAME FTP  statement as shown above.

Something like this :

```
    #!/bin/bash
    input="~/Input.txt"
    while IFS= read -r line
       do
          echo "$line" 
          perl -p -i.orig -e 's/(capture group)/\1 %ftps_opts /gi' "$line" 
          echo "done"
      done < "$input"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are the "filename" records always separated by blank lines? Are there any other types of records in the file? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Not always separated by blank lines. Also there can be other statements in each file which do have FILENAME keyword but will not have all the 3 keywords FILENAME , FTP and HOST on such statements. Essentially the particular statement i intend to add to is identified by these 3 keywords until the end of the semicolon for such a statement.

Comment: Do semicolons appear **anywhere** else in the file? Including the password field.

Comment: Yes glenn , they do appear.  Infact most statements in SAS code  usually end with a semicolon as per SAS language syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tell Perl to process the whole file instead of processing it line by line:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(filename[^;]*ftp[^;]*host[^;]*)/$1 %ftps_opts/gi' -- file
```

Comment: Brilliant solution , short and simple .  Thanks